# Cocoa emacs -- open in current space?

Tags: spaces, emacs

I usually use several different spaces (desktops?) for various different tasks.

Unfortunately, cocoa emacs 24.1 (9.0), even when using emacsclient (I do a server start in my init.el file) always opens a document or email response in the space emacs was originally started in.

Aquamacs seems better behaved in this respect, but I prefer cocoa emacs.

Is there a way to change this behavior?

Best,

JRV

Answer (score 1):

I've gotten at least a usable approach, tho not perfect.

The best I could do is the following:

1) don't ever use emacsclient and take start server out of init.el

2) in mission control preferences, uncheck the boxes for "when switching to an application..." and "group windows by application"

If I am editing more than one doc, in different desktops I end up with more than one instance of emacs running,  but I can live with this.  Also, the startup seems to be fast enough for me without emacsclient.

It doesn't look like cocoa emacs is impemented as a document based cocoa app.  Is that the case?

Seems like Macvim handles the multiple document without multiple instance case more gracefully.

Best regards.

JRV